# http:// and https:// web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I developed simple http:// Web service and deployed. Now we are planning to get certificate on the web site. Do I need change in my code? I am new to SSL side.

Please advice me

Comment: This question would be better on [Webmasters.SE]

Comment: Are you using an ASP.NET Web site? If so, no changes. If you are using WCF over IIS then you may need to change your transport bindings.

Comment: It is simple asp.net website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change the config file in any client applications that consume your service to the new URL.

Your web service application should not require any changes.  IIS will handle the transport encryption with the SSL certificate.

This is worth a read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649205.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Easy solution for your problem 
create a class with the code given below

```
public class HttpsReflector : SoapExtensionReflector
{
    public override void ReflectMethod()
    {
        //no-op
    }

    public override void ReflectDescription()
    {
        ServiceDescription description = ReflectionContext.ServiceDescription;
        foreach (Service service in description.Services)
        {
            foreach (Port port in service.Ports)
            {
                foreach (ServiceDescriptionFormatExtension extension in port.Extensions)
                {
                    SoapAddressBinding binding = extension as SoapAddressBinding;
                    if (null != binding)
                    {
                        binding.Location = binding.Location.Replace("http://", "https://");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

change the web config with following

```
<soapExtensionReflectorTypes>

  <add type="xxx.WebServices.HTTP.HttpsReflector, App_code"/>

</soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
```